# Miktex 2.9 on the fly updating works only for one package at the time

Tags: packages, miktex, update

I have set updating packages to `on the fly`.  I am connected to the internet and have already tried several repositories but only one package is downloaded per go.

When running pdflatex (or latexmk) only one package is installed per go and then I receive `LATEX Error: File NameOfPackage.sty not found` for the second package to be installed. In the next run of pdflatex *NamOfPackage* is going to be installed automatically, but the error appears for the next package and so on. I suspect something is wrong with the updating. I tried reinstallation of MikTex and refreshing the FNDB, no effect. Different repositories didn't do the job either.

Anyone an idea how to fix this?

For the record: Windows 10, MikTex 2.9

Comment: Please make a bug report on MiKTeX homepage ...

Comment: Any updates here?

Comment: No. It only occurs on one of my computers, and but there it remains. Eventually however I managed to have all my packages installed